# How can I restrict the scrolling of a UIImageView to the bounds of the UIImage like in iPhoto?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

Here is an image in iPhoto:

[image]

Here is it zoomed in to the top left corner in iPhoto:

[image]

Here is the same image in my app:

[image]

Here it is zoomed in to the top left corner in my app:

[image]

How can I lose the excess grey space surrounding my image and restrict the scrolling to the bounds of the UIImage like iPhoto?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, aside from using a 3rd party library, I solved this problem using:

[iOS. How do I restrict UIScrollview scrolling to a limited extent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905953/ios-how-do-i-restrict-uiscrollview-scrolling-to-a-limited-extent) , adapting the answer to the following methods, which are I hope self explanatory:

```
- (CGRect) methodThatGetsImageSizeOnScreen
{

float frameHeight;
float frameWidth;
float frameXOrigin;
float frameYOrigin;

float threshold;
BOOL thisImageTouchesLeftAndRight;

UIInterfaceOrientation thisOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(thisOrientation)){

    threshold = 748.0/1024.0;

    if ((self.imageToPresent.size.height == self.imageToPresent.size.width) | ((self.imageToPresent.size.height/self.imageToPresent.size.width) > threshold)){

        thisImageTouchesLeftAndRight = NO;

        frameWidth = (748/self.imageToPresent.size.height)*self.imageToPresent.size.width;
        frameHeight = 748;
        frameXOrigin = (1024-frameWidth)/2;
        frameYOrigin = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        thisImageTouchesLeftAndRight = YES;

        frameWidth = 1024;
        frameHeight = (1024/self.imageToPresent.size.width)*self.imageToPresent.size.height;
        frameXOrigin = 0;
        frameYOrigin = (748-frameHeight)/2;
    }
}
else {

    threshold = 768.0/1004.0;

    if ((self.imageToPresent.size.height == self.imageToPresent.size.width) | ((self.imageToPresent.size.width/self.imageToPresent.size.height) > threshold)){

        thisImageTouchesLeftAndRight = YES;

        frameWidth = 768;
        frameHeight = (768/self.imageToPresent.size.width)*self.imageToPresent.size.height;
        frameXOrigin = 0;
        frameYOrigin = (1004-frameHeight)/2;
    }
    else
    {
        thisImageTouchesLeftAndRight = NO;

        frameWidth = (1004/self.imageToPresent.size.height)*self.imageToPresent.size.width;
        frameHeight = 1004;
        frameXOrigin = (768-frameWidth)/2;
        frameYOrigin = 0;
    }


}

CGRect theRect = CGRectMake(frameXOrigin, frameYOrigin, frameWidth, frameHeight);

return theRect;
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scroll{

UIInterfaceOrientation thisOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;

float largeDimension;
float smallDimension;

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(thisOrientation)){

    largeDimension = 1024;
    smallDimension = 748;
}
else{

    largeDimension = 1004;
    smallDimension = 768;

}

CGPoint offset = scroll.contentOffset;

CGRect results = [self methodThatGetsImageSizeOnScreen];


float frameHeight = results.size.height;
float frameYOrigin = results.origin.y;


float frameWidth = results.size.width;
float frameXOrigin = results.origin.x;


//So, we start the limiting of a landscape image in portrait (in the y direction) when we exceed the following criteria:

if((frameHeight*self.scrollView.zoomScale) > largeDimension){

    if(offset.y < self.scrollView.zoomScale*frameYOrigin) offset.y = self.scrollView.zoomScale*frameYOrigin;

    if(offset.y > ((self.scrollView.zoomScale*frameYOrigin)+(frameHeight*self.scrollView.zoomScale)-largeDimension)) offset.y = ((self.scrollView.zoomScale*frameYOrigin)+(frameHeight*self.scrollView.zoomScale)-largeDimension);

}

if((frameWidth*self.scrollView.zoomScale) > largeDimension){

    if(offset.x < self.scrollView.zoomScale*frameXOrigin) offset.x = self.scrollView.zoomScale*frameXOrigin;

    if(offset.x > ((self.scrollView.zoomScale*frameXOrigin)+(frameWidth*self.scrollView.zoomScale)-largeDimension)) offset.x = ((self.scrollView.zoomScale*frameXOrigin)+(frameWidth*self.scrollView.zoomScale)-largeDimension);

}

    // Set offset to adjusted value
    scroll.contentOffset = offset;

//Remember you may want your minimum zoomScale set in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library that does that. Try [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser).